# In Blender 3.0, how can we control instance properties (scale, etc.) by proximity?

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, instances

I've been looking at tutorials and various node tree screenshots, but since the 3.0 release many aspects of Geometry Nodes have changed, making those sources largely irrelevant.

In 3.0, how can we use an Empty to scale / rotate / etc. a bunch of instances?

[image]

<sup>Above: Icospheres generated at each mesh point, and an Empty I want to influence them with.</sup>

My node tree so far:

[image: The beginnings of a node tree for affecting instances by proximity]

I have been trying lots of different things to scale these (100% effect where the Empty is, and tapering off to 0% effect beyond a certain radius, such as the radius of the Empty object).

Also, it would be nice to be able to adjust the falloff curve.

Comment: By the way: the _Geometry Proximity_ node calculates the distance between the location of the original geometry's points or distributed points etc. to the geometry of a target object. Which means the way you connected it, it wouldn't work. The _Object Info_ node's _Geometry_ output has to be plugged into the _Target_ input of the proximity node, and _Source Position_ needs the positions of the "original" points. This will not work with an empty since it has no geometry (see comments below Nathan's answer).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann sort of.  The empty shouldn't be an input, it should just be picked in the Object Info node.  In that case, plugging the location into Source Position is exactly right and the only thing wrong is that the Geometry output of the Group Input needs to plug into the Target input of the Proximity node.  See my just posted answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need geometry proximity to scale by prox to an empty.  You just need to check the distance to the empty:

[image]

Here it is with a falloff curve (using RGB curves node, but a float is a float.)  I'm clamping it to the 0,1 range (and inverting it) before the RGB curve for convenience-- anything more than 1 unit away will get the minimum scale I have in my curve.

Edit: Here's a pic from the file Mentalist offered in comments:

[image]

Gordon Brinkman also offered that we can just use distance instead of subtract+length.

Comment: @MartyFouts If you want to get technical, is an empty geometry?

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer! [Here's a simple .blend](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Ka7d2qdO) for anyone wanting to quickly try this out. (I made some minor changes to Map Range, etc.)

Comment: @MartyFouts There is a difference though, Nathan is correct. While he checks the distance of the Empty object (i.e. one location: the object's origin) to the points, the _Geometry Proximity_ node checks the distance of each point/edge/face (depending on the chosen option) of some geometry to other points.

Comment: @Nathan Just a quick optimization: instead of using two _Vector Math_ nodes, a _Subtract_ and a _Length_ node, you could simply use a single node set to _Distance_.

Comment: Interesting question/answer.

Comment: @Mentalist your blend file is a little different from the answer and picture provided here.

Comment: @common_goldfish I don't see that Mentalist claimed it to be the same ;) On the contrary, quote: "I made some minor changes to Map Range etc." And since the changes are neither affecting the general functionality of the proximity effect nor is Mentalist the author of the answer and its node tree there is no need to exactly copy the screenshot. As many Blender tutors say: it's not important to copy all the exact settings of a tutorial but to understand how it's working.

Comment: @MartyFouts You say it yourself: he said _geometry_ proximity, not just proximity. And you can not calculate any geometry proximity from an empty, since it has no geometry. It's not only that you don't need no geometry proximity, you can't use geometry proximity with an empty.

Comment: @MartyFouts I'm not talking maths, physics or anything here, but Blender. You are confusing what the Geometry Nodes are taking as "geometry". Just try it. Bring two objects via Object Info node in the GN node tree. An empty and let's say a sphere. And then create some setup like this here and try to scale some instances by proximity to those objects. If you use a _Geometry Proximity_ node, try to use the Geometry output from the empty in the Target input to get a Distance result useable for scaling. And then do it with vector math and use the location. And compare the different effects.

Comment: @MartyFouts I think that you're thinking of geo prox as measuring proximity from source geometry, to something else.  That's reasonable, but I don't think that's the right way to think about it.  It's measuring proximity from each vertex to some outside geometry.  "Geometry" here refers to the target, not the source-- maybe more clear if you think about measuring face proximity, which of course doesn't make any sense if we're talking about the source faces.  Because an empty has no geometry, we're testing prox, but not **geo** prox.

Comment: @Nathan  the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/geometry_proximity.html) describes the node precisely the way I'm thinking.  It is the proximity of the geometry to "the given position".  In the case of the empty, that's the location of the empty.  Your answer would be clearer if you explained the difference.

Comment: @MartyFouts Context matters, let's add it to your quote: "Source Position: The given position to calculate the closest location on the target."  This is not saying that the geometry is the source position.  Elsewhere, and used similarly throughout: "The Geometry Proximity node computes the closest location on the **target geometry.**"  The target is thing that provides the geometry.  We are interested in an empty here, hence there is no **target** geometry to which we can measure proximity.  But c'mon, who cares here anyways?  You can do it with object info.  AFAICT, you can't with geo prox.

Comment: @MartyFouts No.  The empty is not the source.  The source is the geometry with vertices with which you are measuring proximity (to some other geometry.)  Just like a vertex weight prox modifier, where the target of the modifier is what you're measuring prox to, although in that case, the proximity is not necessarily to geometry; empties are supported.  If you plug your input geometry into target and your other geo into source, you'll get prox on the source verts-- of which an empty has none-- not the input mesh you want prox on.  Try it.

Comment: @Nathan it works exactly as I described.  See my answer.

Comment: Nathan, thanks again for your answer. It seems some people here really enjoy nitpicking nuances. I think the current 10:1 upvote ratio in your favor speaks for itself, but if it's any vindication, I will affirm that your answer does accomplish what I was after. Marty's answer works as he describes - to accomplish *something else*. I should have included a reference image of my desired result, but I took it to be understood that the purpose of the Empty was to affect *each instance uniquely* using distance - otherwise, a simple slider would suffice. Marty probably meant well, but you nailed it.

Comment: @Mentalist Well, as you said maybe a reference with the desired result would have been helpful. But while Nathan and me somehow intuitively thought of what you meant (and I wouldn't say it's nitpicking) it's hard to explain to someone with a different solution why he got it wrong if he insists on his setup to be working too and we have nothing to backup our assumption you wanted it the other way.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I wouldn't say Marty's answer is "wrong". It accomplishes something different, and I'm happy to have it as well to study from. It just doesn't solve what I was originally trying to solve. Again, my bad for not including a reference pic. It didn't occur to me that there could be different ways to interpret the question. All contributions and feedback are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use a *Geometry Proximity* node if you want, and your setup was close.  Here's a version of your node group that works:

[image: Node group that uses Geometry proximity node]

In this example, notice that I use an *Object Info* node, rather than an input to the Geometry node group.  That gives me the geometry location of the empty. The only other change from your setup was to plug the *distance* output of the Geometry Proximity group into the *Scale* input of the *Instance on Points* node.  This uses the relative position of the empty to control the scale of the icospheres:

[image: demonstration of moving empty controlling icosphere scale]

EDIT: There seems to be a lot of confusion in the comments about the difference between [this approach](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/251024/42221) from the accepted answer and the approach I've described above.  Here's a version of the other approach, simplified to highlight the major difference:

[image: Using a field for control]

The geometry proximity node has been replaced by a proximity calculation using vector math.  Both approaches work with an empty, because both approaches calculate the distance from the target object to a point.  In both cases the point is the location of the empty.  In both cases, the empty can be replaced by other objects, so long as their location is used.

The *difference* as Nathan has pointed out by example in the accepted answer is that my approach gives a single value for distance — the distance between the location of the empty and the nearest face (in the example) of the target object.  (It could be the nearest vertex or edge, depending on settings in the Geometry Proximity node.) The other approach gives the distance between the location of the empty and *every* point on the target object.

Use my approach if you want a single value, ie for uniform scaling of instanced objects.  Use the accepted approach if you want a field of values, ie for scaling that depends on the distance to each instance.

Comment: I added a pic to my answer.  You can see the difference?  But maybe that explains the misunderstanding.  Indeed, you're getting proximity to geometry, and I'm getting proximity to an empty.  The difference is that proximity to geometry is 1 number, shared by all your points, and that proximity to an empty is a per-point attribute.

Comment: @Nathan You're still getting it partially wrong.  There are _two_ objects involved in _either_ proximity calculation.  We're _both_ getting the proximity of an empty to an object.   The part you get right is the part I've been trying to get you to expand on in your answer: the way in which your approach differs is that you get a field for every point and I get a single value.  To the OP _both_ approaches solve their control requirement; they just do so differently.

Comment: for many applications people want uniform control and should use my approach.  For other applications they want falloff and should use yours.

Comment: The difference is only, if you use the _Geometry Proximity_ node as it makes more sense, you can use your grid points where the icospheres are instanced as _Source Position_ and instead of an empty take e.g. a cube. If you now for example put the cube in the middle of the grid, you can scale the icospheres according to their dstance to the cube's mesh so that they are maybe small close to it and larger far from it. And this means they can get larger again in the middle of the cube, because there they are further away from the mesh. This is not possible with an empty's origin point.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann It doesn't work that way.  That's why Nathan added his example.  To get the scaling you describe, use his method. To get uniform scaling use mine.

Comment: This makes it sound like your method would provide uniform scaling while the other does not, but that's not true. You can get both methods to scale uniformly or with a falloff (if you rearrange your nodes). It's just that you can do things with a _Geometry Proximity_ node that are not possible with just a _Vector Math_ node calculating the distance **or** with an empty that has no mesh.

Comment: If you "rearrange the nodes" it's not the same method any more.  You can calculate the distance to an empty using vector math.  Nathan's method does so.  That's not the difference.  The difference is what he and I have both said it is: His approach calculates the distance of the empty from every point on the object, mine calculates it to the nearest vertex, edge, or face, depending on the geometry proximity node settings. He gets a field and I get a single value.  That's it.

Comment: Anyway, the "two methods" I meant was on the one hand using a _Geometry Proximity_ node and on the other hand as Nathan said, it's not necessary you can do it with _Vector Math_. Since Mentalist's own version which he is happy with uses a scaling with distance falloff instead of uniform scaling I guess that's what he asked for in the first place. And this cannot be achieved with your version

Comment: "It would be nice" to have a falling off effect.  That _can_ be achieved in a modification of my version that still relies on the Geometry Proximity node. It _could_ be done precisely the same way as Nathan's falloff curve.

Comment: Why use geometry proximity in the first setup? Just take the distance to the object, the effect is the same, and you don't iterate over the entire geometry to find the nearest face. https://i.imgur.com/Qu0MxnP.png

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady The effect isn't the same.  See the different results in my and Nathan's answer and my explanation.  But Why?  Because that's what the OP used and I thought the question was best answered by showing them how to make their approach work.

Comment: @MartyFouts in Nathan's answer each instance's scale is based on the instance's distance to the empty. In your answer all instances scales are the same and depend on the empty's relative distance. So you can replace your node setup with the one I linked and get the same result, ergo no "geometry proximity" node is required. Geoprox. is useful to find the nearest point/edge/face to a given coordinate, but here all you need is the empty position and eventually (if you aim for Nathan's effect), the instance position.