# Geometry nodes 3.0 controlling values for individual instances using proximity object

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, procedural, geometry-nodes

I have created a system of entirely procedurally generated flowers which involves a spaghetti of groups within groups and instances within instances.

The part that I am having trouble with is controlling the open and closed state using a value, which can be driven by a proximity object.

Is it possible to control values of individual instances?

Edit:

---

I'm basically trying to change a value within an instanced node group from 0.000 - 1.000 based on it's proximity to an empty or geometry. I'm not trying to change the instance transforms within the instance on points node itself.

Many thanks!

Comment: The question title is awfully similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/251022/86891 , does this answer it ?

Comment: Not quite, that question is relation to transforms to the instances. What I'm asking about is changing values within a node group that is being instanced.

Comment: Oh, then I think it's not possible in version 3.0. But I believe you can do it with version 3.1 alpha

Answer (score 2):

Since Blender's Geometry Nodes doesn't have loops for now, you cannot make a flower 100 times in a row. Also, you cannot modify the flower after it was instanced, because it will be very tricky in your case. So I suggest the following:

Instead of making the flower and when distribute it on surface, do the opposite thing: distribute the root thing on the surface and then add flowers and leafs on every root thing at the same time

Comment: Thanks, this sounds promising. It will take a moment to 'invert' the node tree but I will give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide a blend file (and even no screenshot with your proximity) so we can check it out...of course you can control individual instances.
Here is the basic setup and how it works:

[image]

[image]

if you want help with your setup, provide your blend file.